# Wordpress ReWrite API redirect without changing address bar

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a very simple redirect rule set up as follows:

```
function site_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
    '^products/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?category=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?product=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'site_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

I have all query vars etc set up by the Pods plugin. (Could this have anything to do with pods? Don't really know, but thought I'd throw the idea out there)

Unfortunately when I use this the URL in the address bar is rewritten, so my address bar actually reads `index.php?product=example` when it should read `products/category/example`.

I'm sure it shouldn't do that, as that's redirecting, not rewriting.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was something todo with wordpress's canonical redirect.
No idea why it was broken, but i found a better way of doing it using the Pods plugin.